# Webservice Method generic list fill and keep for 1 day

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a webmethod inside a webservice that calls another webservice to get data and fills a generic list then it returns it, what i want to do is to save the list in memory, so the next time the webmethod is invoked it does not hit the other webservice but just returns the list, i have tried but when i invoke the web method for the second time the list count shows as 0, looks like garbage collection is cleaning all. any suggestions ?

Comment: Could it be the app pool is recycling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in the ASP.NET cache.  Setting an absolute expiration of midnight should assure that you only get it once per day (unless it gets tossed from the cache due to space issues).

```
 [Web Method]
 public List<Foo> GetFoos()
 {
      var foos = Cache["FooList"] as List<Foo>;
      if (foos == null)
      {
          ... get foos from remote web service ...
          var expiration = DateTime.Today.AddHours(7);
          if (DateTime.Now >= expiration)
          {
              expiration = expiration.AddDays(1);
          }
          Cache.Insert( "FooList", foos, null, expiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration );
      }

      return foos;
 }
```

Note: you could also use output caching as well, but you're limited to a sliding expiration.  That is, it will be cached for a duration based on when the request occurs.  It's not clear that's what you want.  For example, what if the first request occurs at 11pm with a 24 hour duration, you wouldn't check again until 11pm the next day.  If you have data changing on a daily basis, you're better off using the ASP.NET cache in conjunction with output caching on a shorter duration to ensure that you get the latest, daily data in a timely fashion.

**Updated example based on comments.**

Comment: thanks for the help, is it possible to cache from 7 am to 7 am of next day after this period the webmethod automatically fills the list with new data

Comment: @AI25 sure, `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(7)`.  That is, midnight (AM) of today, add a day to get to midnight (AM) of tomorrow, then add 7 hours to get to 7AM.  That should keep it in the cache (assuming it's not thrown out to make space) until 7AM of the following day regardless of when the request occurs.  Note, you need to check if it's between midnight and 7AM already.  I'll update my example.

Comment: i am getting the following error at this line                          var foos =  Cache["FooList"] as List<Foo>;  'System.Web.Caching.Cache' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: You might need to reference it from the HttpContext as in, `Context.Cache["FooList"]`  If your method is in a WebService class, I don't think the Cache is exposed directly.  If it's in a Page class, then it should be available directly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like your list might either not be static, or it might constantly be `new`'d within a non-static constructor. There are three possible fixes for this:

1. Make sure that your generic list is a static property which only get initialised within a static constructor.
2. Seeing your time requirements I would also suggest potentially looking into [`MemoryCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) or [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).
3. Use the `WebMethod` attribute and set a `CacheDuration` (i.e: `[WebMethod(CacheDuration=86400)]`)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this on a webservice, but I think [output cashing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318299) would work.

```
[WebMethod(CacheDuration=86400)]
public string FunctionName(string Name)
{
    ...code...
    return(sb.ToString());
}
```

Read: [How to perform output caching with Web services in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318299)

Comment: ok, i have a question does cache is client dependent ? i.e each client will have a its own cache, my list data will be same for all

Comment: If the list is the same, it will only be cached once by the server.